# Efficient Sharing of Numpy Arrays in Multiprocess

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, numpy-ndarray

I have two multi-dimensional Numpy arrays loaded/assembled in a script, named `stacked` and `window`. The size of each array is as follows:

`stacked`: (1228, 2606, 26)

`window`: (1228, 2606, 8, 2)

The goal is to perform statistical analysis at each i,j point in the multi-dimensional array, where:

1. i,j of `window` is a subset collection of eight i,j points
2. These eight i, j points are used to extract values across the entirety of the `stacked` array and assemble them into a list
3. Statistical analysis is then performed by scipy on this list, with the resultant then prepared for use

The portion of this script is as follows:

```
def statagg(queue, startrng, endrng):
    for stepone in range(startrng,endrng,1):
        for steptwo in range(0,2606,1):
            selection = window[stepone][steptwo]
            piece = stacked[selection[:,0], selection[:,1]].tolist()
            piece = [j for i in piece for j in i]
            piece = [(i * 0.0393701) for i in piece]
            piece = [0 if math.isnan(i) else i for i in piece]
            param = sci.stats.gamma.fit(piece)
            x = np.linspace(0, max(piece), 500)
            cdf = sci.stats.gamma.cdf(x, *param)

def parallelstats():
    processes = []
    q = mpr.Queue()
    for step in range(600,701,1):
        pro = mpr.Process(target=statagg, args=(q, step, step + 1))
        processes.extend([pro])
        pro.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

I've elected to use a 100 row chunk to test this process and am initiating parallel processes of `statagg` with Multiprocess. Upon execution, I've noticed that these parallel processes in total consume ~8.5-9.0 GB of RAM, which seems unusually high given both `stacked` and `window` have been declared once outside of the function executing tasks in parallel. The entries in each list only total 200-210, which I also expected consume minimal amounts of memory.

What steps can I take to make this process more efficient in memory, such that I can conduct the statistical analysis with Scipy at a much faster pace?

Comment: What OS are you one? You will only get the benefits of COW if you use fork, which isn't supported on Windows for example.

Comment: Excellent question, I'm using Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.2 specifically)